# Signed Hex Division by Decimal

Tags: c, hex, division, signed

I am not sure about signed hex division by decimal.

How can `long` type `fff0bdc0` divided by `1000L` turn to be `fffffc18`?

```
   long a = 0xfff0bdc0;
   a = a/1000L;
   UARTprintf("a = %x\n", a);
```

**result of print : a = fffffc18**

Thanks,

Jin

Comment: Better show your code.  The result should be 0x41854f.

Comment: no it shouldnt! how did you get a positive number when you divided a negative one?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm thinking in 64 bits.  On a platform with 32-bit longs, you're correct, it would be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `long` is a 32-bit integer, and negative numbers are represented using the
[two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

```
fff0bdc0 (hex) = -1000000 (decimal)
fffffc18 (hex) =    -1000 (decimal)
```

So your result looks correct.